# Многопоточность в одном методе

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть метод, который декомпресит файл, но этот процесс довольной долгий (а файлов 130+). Я решил реализовать это многопоточно.

```
for (int i = 0; files.length > i; i++) { //foreach тут не подойдёт.
    try {
        Decoder.main(files[i].getName(), true);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

Каким образом заставить 2 потока работать над 1 методом? Я могу разбить этот массив на несколько частей, и запустить потоки к каждой, но меня это не совсем устраивает.

Comment: Чем не устраивает?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, хочу попробовать пойти другим путём. Но если это не выгодно, то буду делать разбивать.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь Fork/Join.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);

Arrays(files).stream()
             .map(File::getName)
             .<Runnable>map(name -> () -> Decoder.main(name, true))
             .forEach(executor::execute);

executor.shutdown();
```